# Is there a dedicated data type for storing amounts in CnosDB？

Tags: cnosdb

Is there a dedicated data type for storing amounts in CnosDB, or which data type do you recommend?

In CnosDB, I did not find a no dedicated data type for storing amounts. However, the DECIMAL data type can be used to store monetary values. DECIMAL is a precise numeric data type that can ensure the accuracy of decimal fractions, and is often recommended for storing monetary values. Other numeric data types in CnosDB include INT, BIGINT, FLOAT, and DOUBLE, but they may not be as suitable for storing monetary values due to potential precision loss.